# What was Aken Bosch's actual objective?

Tags: video-games, freespace-2

In Freespace 2, Admiral Aken Bosch, leader of the rebel NTF, leads a crusade culminating in him seemingly joining with the Shivans. While the various cut-scenes make it sound like Bosch's motives were for the good of humanity, the number of people the Shivan's kill and the destruction of a star would seem to belie this. While the final cut-scene speculates on the Shivan's purpose in destroying the star, what was Bosch's true purpose in seeking out and joining with the Shivans?

Comment: This was never actually answered in the game and there is no additional lore outside of the game. It was left open for a possible sequel (which will never come to be). Any answer would not be canon.

Comment: @Resorath That is unfortunate. I was really hoping there had been some official word on the story outside of the game.

Comment: Regardless of Bosch's intentions, don't the Shivans basically kidnap him and kill most of his fleet? It looks more like a kidnapping than Bosch "joining" the Shivans.

Comment: @AndresF. Bosche opened the portal and jumped into the nebula. Regardless of how he came into their possession at the end, he wanted to at least get their attention.

Comment: @Xantec Yes, agreed. Just saying I didn't get the impression he "joined" the Shivans. He certainly wanted something from them, but I think his plan backfired. Regrettably, we'll never know...